# characterAtIndex conversion to NSString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I am getting the error message `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short')  to parameter of type 'NSString *'` on the last line of this code.

```
NSMutableString *sp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"             "];
NSArray *deals=@[@[sp, sp, sp, sp], @[sp, sp, sp, sp]];
NSString* suits = @"NESW";
[deals[0][3] replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1) withString:[suits characterAtIndex:2]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `characterAtIndex:` returns a unichar while `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` needs an NSString. Try `substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,1)` instead if you want an NSString with the character at index 2.